# React-Native link Cannot find module 'lodash/object/assign

Tags: react-native

I have issue when I try run command react-native link, I get error: `Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/object/assign'.`
I don't understand how to fix this and I don't find any good question from web. My package.json dependencies installed packages

```
{
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.47.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
}
```

Thanks if someone can help me :)

Comment: Are you referring to lodash at all in your project?

Comment: No, it's very starting point react-native application.

Comment: So why are you running `react-native link`?

Comment: You need to go through each of your dependencies and find out which one has the problem. Also why are you using "whatwg-fetch"? fetch is already polyfilled in to react native

Comment: @MattyK14 Because it was in nativebase documentation. Same error comes also when try run react-native run-android command.

Comment: @KyleRoach Already started check dependencies, but not yet found anything. whatwg-fetch using... Good question :)

Comment: try `npm install --save lodash`. I would also try updating `Node`.

Comment: @MattyK14 Already tried install lodash, not worked. I installed all packages again to new folder, also copied all files then old error was gone, new one is cannot find module accessibility, need reinstall again and check which package affects this error.

Comment: I've seen the `AccessibilityInfo` error a decent amount lately. What works for me is stopping the packager & `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: This one not work for me. So I will install one by one packages and find package where issue is

Comment: All packages installed to new directory, copied all  components etc files. Now finally there is issue which is really linked to my code :) Thanks of help MattyK14 & KyleRoach.